# Uri to default sound notification?

Tags: android, notifications, uri

I use the [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) to build a notification.
Now I want to use the default sound notification with:

```
builder.setSound(Uri sound)
```

But where is the Uri to the default notification?

Answer (score 279, accepted):

try using [RingtoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) to get Default Notification Uri as:

```
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

builder.setSound(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have seen i can use setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND) too ;-)

Comment: you can pass this one also `Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI`

Answer (score 46):

`builder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)` works as well

Comment: Settings comes from import android.provider.Settings;

Answer (score 29):

#### The two options to use the `Default Notification Sound` are:

```
mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```

or using [**RingtoneManager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html) Class:

```
mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
```

Comment: Doesn't setDefaults(int) erase other defaults if you don't OR them?

Answer (score 12):

**all of these methods work**

1. `mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));`
2. `mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);`
3. `mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);`

[Google Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html)

Answer (score 5):

For system default notification

```
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

For custom notification

```
Uri customSoundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.twirl);
```

Source of notification sound (I renamed to "twirl" and placed in
res->raw folder)

https://notificationsounds.com/message-tones/twirl-470

Notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificaion_icon)
                        .setContentTitle("Title here")
                        .setContentText("Body here")
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);



NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotifyMgr.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this as well:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).
            getString("pref_tone", "content://settings/system/notification_sound"));
mBuilder.setSound(uri);
```

Comment: I want to get `application` channel sound not default system sound tried with  `NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ApplicationClass.getInstance().HighNotificationChannelID, getString(R.string.incoming_sms), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                channel.getSound();` returns  `default system sound` please help

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still need, this works absolutely fine with sound and vibration.

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
    long[] vibrate = new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 };
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif)
            .setTicker("lastWarning")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(vibrate)
            //.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) 
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
            .setContentText("Notification text"); 

    // Notification notification = builder.getNotification(); // until API 16
    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
```

If you would like disable for example vibration change vibrate to new long[] { 0,0,0,0,0};
Almost similar thing you can do with sound or use if else statement.