# Vibrate and Sound defaults on notification

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a default vibrate and sound alert when my notification comes in, but so far no luck. I imagine it's something to do with the way I set the defaults, but I'm unsure of how to fix it. Any thoughts?

```
public void connectedNotify() {
    Integer mId = 0;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
            .setContentTitle("Device Connected")
            .setContentText("Click to monitor");

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =     
          PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 
          0, 
          resultIntent,  
          PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    Notification note = mBuilder.build();
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(mId, note);

}
```

Comment: All the answers only reiterate some variation of the code you already have, and none of them answers the question in my opinion. Your code looks fine, AFAICT. Most likely, you're just missing `android.permission.VIBRATE` in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: To whom that may apply solutions in this thread and still does not have any vibration on notifications, you may need to enable vibration of your notification channel first. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646166/8551764

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Some dummy code might help you.

```
   private static NotificationCompat.Builder buildNotificationCommon(Context _context, .....) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).......;
     //Vibration
        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
 
     //LED
        builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
 
     //Ton
        builder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));
 
    return builder;
   }
```

Add below permission for Vibration in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Comment: +1 `vibrate` feature requires `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` permission

Comment: In some cases you should use hex color argb format, like 0xffffffff, instead of Color.White, because there's is a small chance of user device use Color(RGB) for a ARGB param and you will get the wrong color. This Happened with me.

Comment: The vibration now has a delay of 1000 ms. If you set the first one to 0, it will go off instantly. It's a { delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep } pattern.

Comment: I haven't needed to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` to work.

Comment: Anyone knows how to use setSound on API 26?

Answer (score 61):

An extension to TeeTracker's answer,

to get the default notification sound you can do as follows

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
            .setContentTitle("Device Connected")
            .setContentText("Click to monitor");

Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
```

This will give you the default notification sound.

Answer (score 37):

**Notification**
**Vibrate**

```
mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});
```

**Sound**

```
mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```

[for more sound option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29250664/2314592)

Comment: For the vibrate one, be sure to include the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: how long does this vibrate go for? or will it just vibrate once?

Answer (score 14):

Its work fine to me,You can try it.

```
 protected void displayNotification() {

        Log.i("Start", "notification");

      // Invoking the default notification service //
        NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message");
        mBuilder.setContentText("You have "+unMber_unRead_sms +" new message.");
        mBuilder.setTicker("New message from PayMe..");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

      // Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives //
        mBuilder.setNumber(unMber_unRead_sms);

      // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app //

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, FreesmsLog.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(FreesmsLog.class);

      // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack //
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

      //  mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
        Notification note = mBuilder.build();
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. //
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a simple way to call notification by using default vibrate and sound from system.

```
private void sendNotification(String message, String tick, String title, boolean sound, boolean vibrate, int iconID) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Notification notification = new Notification();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    if (sound) {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    }

    if (vibrate) {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }

    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(notification.defaults);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(iconID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setTicker(tick)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Add vibrate permission if you are going to use it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Good luck,'.

Comment: Can someone tell me why vibration is not working when phone is in call ? OR can we make notification to force vibrate even in phone is in call

Comment: It helped me   notificationBuilder.setDefaults(notification.defaults);

Comment: @user526206, I dont know. I have never tested that. You can open new question since this has nothing with notification behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I m using the followung code and its working fine for me .

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To support SDK version >= 26, you also should build NotificationChanel and set a vibration pattern and sound there. There is a Kotlin code sample:

```
    val vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(500)
    val soundUri = "<your sound uri>"

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager =    
                 getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val attr = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .build()
            val channelName: CharSequence = Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, importance)
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
                notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, attr)
                notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = vibrationPattern
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
    }
```

And this is the builder:

```
 with(NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)) {
        setContentTitle("Some title")
        setContentText("Some content")
        setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
        setAutoCancel(true)    
        setVibrate(vibrationPattern)
        setSound(soundUri)
        setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
        setContentIntent(
            // this is an extension function of context you should build
            // your own pending intent and place it here
            createNotificationPendingIntent(
                Intent(applicationContext, target).apply {
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                }
            )
        )

        return build()
    }
```

Be sure your `AudioAttributes` are chosen right to read more [here](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/attributes).

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin you can Try this.

```kotlin
var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
     .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
     .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
```

Answer (score 2):

// set notification audio

```
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
//OR 
builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
```