# How to get ringing and vibration alert on incoming messages in google's guestbook android sample app?

Tags: android, notifications, alert, google-cloud-messaging, vibration

I am working on push notification using  google cloud messaging ... I am using google's guestbook sample app... I exported it with my project id and api keys ... I want that when any user of this app sends a message it should received by all other user of this app with vibration or ringing alert  wheter they are using or not using this app....like the message notification we get for facebook chat or whatsapp messanger when we even are offline..

So please suggest me how can I add homescreen notification with alert tone and vibrations for this android app?

Comment: `when we even are offline` you aren't really. The app is using a background service to fetch the incoming messages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vibrate and Sound defaults on notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253482/vibrate-and-sound-defaults-on-notification)