# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification Vibration

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to make an Android device vibrate when receiving notifications in the background with Firebase Cloud Messaging? From the [Syntax Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) I have seen and tested that sound is supported, but no info on vibration. Or is it somehow possible to provide a customized implementation for this notification where I would directly set the vibration?

Comment: I think you need to implement on upon building the Notification. Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18253482/4625829) before?

Comment: The thing with FCM is that when a notification is sent and the application is in the background the [Notification is built internally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications). I think the solution to customizing the notification is to only deliver a data payload, thus [guaranteeing that my service's onMessageReceived() method will be called](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) and then building the notification in the method implementation

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42555899/firebase-push-notifications-vibrate-in-background

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I have tested the format of the FCM Notification message seems to be quite rigid, so for customized notifications, the solution seems to be:

1. Making sure that the payload of the JSON message being sent downstream contains the `data` parameter but **doesn't** contain the `notification` parameter (Sources: [Message JSON Syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json), [FCM Message Types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages))
2. Creating the Notification in the implementation of the overridden `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` from the application's `FirebaseMessagingService` ([Example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java))

Comment: is this just Notification **sound** or also **vibration**?

Comment: What if I use same message for iOS and Android? I cannot avoid `notification` object in the message. Adding `sound` field doesn't vibrate in the background though...

Answer (score 30):

You should mark yourself as a correct answer.

On a sidenote, if you do send a Notification and a Data payload, use

```
"notification":{
    "sound":"default"
}
```

This will play the sound when the application is in background and the device is set to sound, and it will play a vibration if the device is set to vibrate.

However, as far as customization goes I think you need to use the Data Payload only if you want to customize the vibration pattern for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's now supported by Firebase. The notification should look like this:

```
{...
    default_vibrate_timings: false,
    vibrate_timings: [
                "0.0s",
                "0.2s",
                "0.1s",
                "o.2s"
     ],
...}
```

[Official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidConfig)

Answer (score -6):

`array("title"=>"hello","body" =>"hello world",'sound' => 'default')`

Comment: function send_notification($tokens,$notification)
{

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $priority="high";
    

    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'notification' => $notification

        );