# Notification Vibration Not Working

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to set vibration for firebase notification 
but I think I am not doing it right

here is a code,

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notification.setContentTitle("NEW NOTIFICATION");
        notification.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notification.setLargeIcon(icon);
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
        notification.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});


    }
```

Comment: i think you need to enable vibration in firebase console. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446300/firebase-cloud-messaging-notification-vibration)

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the `Notification` *before* calling `notify()`. You are calling `setVibrate()` *after* calling `notify()`. Move your `setVibrate()` call to be before the `notify()` call.

Also note that you need to have a `<uses-permission>` element for the `VIBRATE` permission in your manifest.

Comment: Ok.. let me chack

Comment: No Change
`notification.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000});
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notification.build());`