# Notification vibrate issue for android 8.0

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

i create notification channel to show notification in android 8.0 as below

```
 NotificationChannel uploadChannel = new NotificationChannel(Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_UPLOAD_ID,"Uploads", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
 uploadChannel.enableLights(false);
 uploadChannel.setDescription("Uploads Channel");
 notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(uploadChannel);
```

each time i show notification the phone vibrate many times. 
i disable vibrate from notification channel as below

```
uploadChannel.enableVibration(false);
```

i create notification as below

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_UPLOAD_ID);
```

but it is not working phone is vibrating with each notification.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bug on Android 8 notification system. I've tinkered with different combinations of `enableVibration` with `setVibrationPattern(null)` but it does not work.

Only solution that stops the vibration for me is this:

```
mNotificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0 });
mNotificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
```

FYI, even if I set a vibration pattern with 0, but set `enableVibration` to `false`, it vibrates.

Comment: if it doesn't work refer to [Roland van der Linden's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402510/notification-vibrate-issue-for-android-8-0/51289889#51289889)

Comment: Did they fix it? Will this hack be working till the next "P" version?

Comment: @KirillReznikov Just tested on Android 9 and this hack still works, and they haven't fixed it yet..

Answer (score 25):

In addition to [Ahmadul Hoq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402510/notification-vibrate-issue-for-android-8-0/47646166#47646166), which did work for me, I would like to add that you may need to remove the app and reinstall it before the vibration changes take place. The channel keeps its initial settings and stays alive if the app is killed - so changes may not be applied if you simply build and run.

Comment: Does this mean that we can no longer give the user the option to change notification vibration settings? I wonder how Whatsapp is doing it?

Comment: @behelit Developers are very likely to apply Admadul's changes, run the app and test the outcome. In this specific case, the changes do not apply directly which is confusing during development. I'm fairly sure you could also reboot the device and have a similar effect. I don't think this means users can't change notification vibration settings anymore.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just **Clear App Data**

Comment: If you want to apply changes made to a notification channel on production and to users that currently have your app installed, change your channel id to a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I was initially using `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` and could not get the vibrating to stop. Using `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW` instead resolved the issue. `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN` would also work; see here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#importance

Answer (score 2):

This function worked for me. With it I create the notification channel in what fully disable lights, vibration and sound.

```
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );

            serviceChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0 });
            serviceChannel.enableVibration(true);
            serviceChannel.enableLights(false);
            serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add `notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0L });`
uninstall the application or clear App Data. run it again It will work!
reason: channel_id already registered for application.