# Cannot disable notification vibration in Android 8

Tags: android, android-notifications

I try to **disable vibration** when showing a notification.

Func:

```
public static Notification buildNotifForUploaderService(Context ctx, String title, String message) {

        Notification notification;
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

        //If device is Android 8+
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            //setting pattern to disable vibrating
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0L});
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, CHANNEL_ID);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
            notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
        }


        notificationBuilder
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_backup_black_24dp);


        notification = notificationBuilder.build();

        return notification;
    }
```

I call this on an activity's onCreate() like this:

```
Notification notification = NotificationHelper.buildNotifForUploaderService(this, "title", "message");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

It is **still vibrating**. I test on **Android 8** device.
I have also tried

```
 notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(null);
```

still not works.

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

**No matter how I define the vibration pattern**, like:

```
new long[]{1000L, 500L, 300L, 1000L};
```

The vibration **does not correspond to my settings**. Onyl the default "two short" vibration occurs.

Please help if you can, thanks in advance.

**E D I T:**

As Avijit Karmakar mentioned, **I have added**

```
  notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
```

**Full code** now:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static String CHANNEL_ID = "MY_CHANNEL_ID";
    final static String CHANNEL_NAME = "MY_CHANNEL_NAME";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Notification notification;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        //Disabling vibration!
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

    } else {
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
    }

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(bm);

    notification = mBuilder.build();
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

---

### It is still vibrating.

I test on Xiaomi Mi A1 (Android 8.0)

Can anybody try this code and help me with the results?

Comment: simply remove vibrate permission from manifest and try once

Comment: @AkshayKatariya Doesn't work

Comment: Remember that it's `Only modifiable before the channel is submitted to notify(String, int, Notification)` for the first time. Read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableVibration(boolean)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification vibrate issue for android 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402510/notification-vibrate-issue-for-android-8-0)

Answer (score 23):

Like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646166/6031927), do:

```
mNotificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0 }); 
mNotificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
```

**Important 1**: even if I set the vibration pattern above, but set enableVibration to false, it vibrates. So, set enableVibration to **true**!

**Important 2**: like this [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51289889/6031927), the channel keeps its initial settings, so **uninstall** and install the app again to apply the changes!

Hope it helps!

Comment: remember folks to UNINSTALL the app... I had another application flavor installed and got frustrated until I realised it uses the same channel!

Comment: After hours of dealing with this problem **Important 2** worked for me!

Comment: I would add **Important 3**: call `setSound(null, null)` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60083773/1346778), since phones on vibrate mode will still vibrate if a sound is present

Answer (score 17):

Use NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW for importance value.

```
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
    CHANNEL_ID,
    CHANNEL_NAME,
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
);
```

Comment: Finally! If you think vibration is an intrusive act(is it?, finding the solution was) then this should be accepted answer

Comment: Yes, it's works. But after that, the application needs to be reinstalled - see **Important 2** in the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207215/8313316) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code to stop vibration:

```
notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);
// Above line will disable your vibration for the notification
```

Also, remove the vibration pattern.

So, your updated code will be:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    //setting pattern to disable vibrating
    notificationChannel.enableVibration(false);

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, CHANNEL_ID);
} else {
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0L});
}
```

Comment: In theory, this should work -- but as others have stated, it does not.

Comment: Combining this solution to setting Importance to Min works for me.
Importance Default still gives the vibration.

Comment: Importance "LOW" was the key for me

Answer (score 1):

The answer of [Ahmadul Hoq](http://Ahmadul%20Hoq) which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646166/5555438) might be helpful.

Basically you have to enable vibration and set the vibration pattern to 0L.
There seems to be a bug on Android Oreo which causes this workaround.

EDIT:

If you are using summary notification this might cause the double vibration. I had the same behaviour until I found out that the summary notification which was grouped together with the incoming notification was causing this issue. You can create an extra notification channel for the summary notification and set the importance for this one to "low". This means the channel for the summary notification will be silent and you should only have sound and vibration coming from the normal incoming notifications.

Comment: I had the exact same problem you described in your edit. Your fix helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

This function worked for me. With it I create the notification channel in what fully disable lights, vibration and sound.

```
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        serviceChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0 });
        serviceChannel.enableVibration(true);
        serviceChannel.enableLights(false);
        serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
```